# Cannot Capture Mutable List Mockk

Tags: kotlin, mockk

Kotlin error when compiling such code mentioned in https://mockk.io/#capturing. What's wrong actually?

```
class Foo{
   fun fx(parm: MutableList<Double>) {}
}

val foo = Foo()
val parm: MutableList<Double> = mutableListOf()

every { foo.fx(capture(parm)) }
```

Error written below

```
Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is Double but MutableList<Double> was expected
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `capture` function expects either a `Slot` - when you want to capture the parameter of a single invocation - or `MutableList` - when attempting to capture the parameters of multiple invocations. Both of type `T`, where `T` is the type of the parameter. This has to be used in conjunction with `verify`, not with `every`.

So you have to use either of the two mechanisms to capture the call arguments.

```kotlin
val param = slot<MutableList<Double>>()
verify { foo.fx(capture(param)) }

// or
val params = mutableListOf<MutableList<Double>>()
verify { foo.fx(capture(params)) }
```

Also, this only works with a mocked object.
So instead of creating an actual object of type `Foo`, you would need to create a mock of it.

```kotlin
// set up the mock
val foo = mockk<foo>()
every { foo.func(any()) } just runs

// call the mocked function, most likely you want to do this indirectly instead
foo.fx(mutableListOf())

// assert that the function has been called
val slot = slot<MutableList<Double>>()
verify { foo.fx(capture(slot)) }
val param = slot.captuted

// assert what the function actually has been called with - this example uses "Hamkrest"
assertThat(param, hasSize(equalTo(0)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, it works. I was misunderstood the usage of Slot and MutableList. I thought that MutableList used when the argument is in List type, but as you mentioned, it's used when multiple invocation's argument were expected to be recorded